# Conversion from string to double

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

in this app for the calculation of the determinant, I'm using a java parser formel: http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_java/index.html in order to allow the user to enter in  input also  mathematical expressions. But the app crashes

```
secondo = new Button (this);
secondo.setText("Fill the matrix and CALCULATE");
tableLayout.addView(secondo);
secondo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

expr[i][j] = valore[i][j].getText().toString();  
matrix[i][j] = prs.parse(expr[i][j]);

}
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

int index1 = matrix[i][j].indexOf("=");

matrix1[i][j] = matrix[i][j].substring(index1+2);

}
}
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
for(int j = 0; j < 3;  j++){

vettore1[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(matrix1[i][j]);
}
}

Matrix A = new Matrix(vettore1);
det = A.det();
```

This code gives me this error:

```
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDblImpl(Native Method)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:283)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:326)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at it.bisemanuDEV.matrixDET.SecondaAttivita$1.onClick(SecondaAttivita.java:143)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:603)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-07 17:59:09.138: E/AndroidRuntime(2420):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's a `NumberFormatException`. Are you sure `matrix1[i][j]` contains numbers as `String`s and nothing else?

Comment: Coming to think of it, I think you were the one who posted a question regarding `sin30` and other such mathematical functions. Have you parsed your input accordingly before trying to convert it to `Double`?

Comment: Yes, is in fact the same code that i have used in a simple java app and works fine, but in android app gives me error

Comment: I think someone with an idea about the parser you are using would have a better idea about what is going wrong here. You could have used my workaround,was a simpler solution. :-)

Comment: I am proving both of them, yours solution too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Generall **NumberFormatException**  occurs when you are converting invalid string to number

for ex:  `matrix1[i][j]="21.21"` then it's ok

but if  `matrix1[i][j]="a21.21"` `<--` it will give you **NumberFormatException**

in you case `vettore1[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(matrix1[i][j]);`

try to check your response string  by printing values
use `LOG` or `System.out.println(matrix1[i][j]);`
to test all your response values

Answer (score 0):

put this line in try catch as in string there possibility of non-number character

```
if(matrix1[i][j]!=null && matrix1[i][j].trim().length()>0)
try{
             vettore1[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(matrix1[i][j].trim());
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

   //Toast here the string matrix1[i][j] to check 
 }
```